# samba terminology - server / client or host

Tags: samba

My task is to use my PC for software development and use Raspberry Pi as a controller of hardware. I have the network working. 
Now I need to implement samba. 
Have a stupid , basic , question - who is in charge of this networking? 
AKA **who is samba server and who is client ? PC or Pi ?** 
In my terminology -  PC Eclipse work space should reside in Raspberry Pi, probably on shared external USB drive or Desktop - whichever is allowed by Linux security or is simpler and can be executed in Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is the one running a service, any service. In this case smbd. Anyone using this service is a client. The Pi3 is more than capable of serving SMB/CIFS, though if you get jitter, try doing it over LAN connection to see if that's the cause.

Comment: Please clarify or just say yes - if I want to share device , such as USB drive on Pi will I program / set it as samba SERVER?Sorry to be so dense , but...terminology is sometime confusing ( to me ) confusing or vague.

Comment: @JanHus Your Pi is a server.